# Classification of homomorphisms of matrix algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Is there a classification of homomorphisms of matrix algebras
$$Mat_{k\times k}(\mathbb{C})\to Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$$
say up to conjugacy?

Comment: This question seems better-suited for Math.SE.

Comment: Look at [Skolem-Noether theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem–Noether_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I assume you want them to be $\mathbb{C}$-linear. If $F$ is any field then the matrix ring $M_k(F)$ is [semisimple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module) and $F^k$ is the unique simple module, meaning every module is a direct sum of copies of $F^k$. It follows that a homomorphism $M_k(F) \to M_n(F)$ of $F$-algebras (equivalently, an $n$-dimensional module over $M_k(F)$) exists iff $k \mid n$ and is unique up to conjugacy, and up to conjugacy it is given by diagonal blocks

$$X \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} X & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 & X & \cdots & 0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & \cdots & X \end{array} \right].$$

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @semyon: unfortunately I don't. This follows from a computation showing that $M_k(F)$ is simple (in the sense that it has no nontrivial two-sided ideals) together with the fact that simple + Artinian implies semisimple. Probably one can also give a direct proof of the classification of modules. Maybe this stuff is in Curtis and Reiner (https://www.amazon.com/Representation-Associative-Algebras-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/0821840665).